# encrypting hidden variables in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, jakarta-ee

We've got user SSN's in jsp's that show in source code of an html page as:

`<a href="onclick:submitsomeform(123456789)"`

In order to avoid this, I made couple of methods called `getEncryptedSSN()` and `getDecryptedSSN()` which could be called from the JSP.  These methods made use of the `javax.crypto` to encrypt/decrypt the ssn string, however, this import is `"disallowed"` by the setup coding standards.  So now I'm out of options on how to avoid showing the SSN in the view source of HTML.  We can not go the route of not passing the SSN in form submit because in the DB, the SSN field is the only primary field.

Are there any other ways to simply encrypt/decrypt a string in java w/out using `javax.crypto`?

Comment: "this import is "disallowed" by the setup coding standards" can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: sure I can. In two words its bullshit bureaucracy. In explanation, there is a layer on top of us that 'builds' the code based on ant scripts. these build scripts have a set allowed of imports that can be used in the source code.  If the source code contains anything outside these imports, the build fails and gives 'checkstyle' error. I can put in a request for `javax.crypto` to be allowed, however, that will go through a big review in which i'm pretty sure they will force us to do everything over again (DB design wise). rather than simply allowed `javax.crypo`.

Comment: If a review is going to force a re-design of this DB table (hopefully to not use SSN as a primary key) this may not be a bad thing... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious option is to just write your own encryptian function. You probably aren't going to write something as secure as the big-time security folks have come up with, but depending on the context, something simple might be adequate, i.e. something that would frustrate the casual snooper, and accept that if the CIA or Mosad or whoever is trying to crack your encryptian, they'll figure it out in minutes. I don't know how big a target you are for hackers. If you're working for a bank or the IRS or something where lots of people might well be trying to intercept your transactions and the consequences of interception are high, forget it, you want industrial-grade security. But if you're working for Joe's Pet Care Advice Swap Forum and there's no particularly sensitive information involved other than the SSN itself, and there's no great number of enemies out to get you, a home-grown solution might be adequate.

Comment: this is the approach I'm leaning towards.

Comment: There is no need for encryption here -- if you keep a reference map on the server side, the generated id or string you use has no meaning beyond the user's session.

Comment: @David: An SSN is sensitive information. It may fall into the category of acceptable risk, but I'd want to make some effort to protect it.

Comment: @Jay: Correct -- SSN is sensitive.  Using a reference map that is stored server side means that the SSN (or any encrypted/encoded form of it) is never passed to the client... this is one of the points OWASP makes: a direct object reference is sensitive information that end-users should not see.  In this case the SSN is both an object reference and a piece of sensitive information in and of itself.  @Omnipresent Base64 is barely better than plaintext...

Comment: @David: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that if you can redesign the system to not need to accept an SSN from the browser, then no encryptian is necessary. To the extent that this app is using SSN as a primary key and passing it all over the place, absolutely true. That's a bad design decision. But if there's any screen where he needs to collect the SSN to begin with, the issue is still there.

Comment: @Omnipresent: I'd do something a step more than a base64 encode. Like, at least create a password and XOR the bytes with this password, or juggle some bits around, or something. Or by the way, can you use https? That encrypts for you.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, having an SSN as a primary key is bad -- but you may not be able to change this.

Have a look at this OWASP page: [Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4):

> Preventing insecure direct object references requires selecting an approach for protecting each user accessible object (e.g., object number, filename):
>
> 1. Use per user or session indirect object references. This prevents attackers from directly targeting unauthorized resources. For example, instead of using the resource’s database key, a drop down list of six resources authorized for the current user could use the numbers 1 to 6 to indicate which value the user selected. The application has to map the per-user indirect reference back to the actual database key on the server. OWASP’s ESAPI includes both sequential and random access reference maps that developers can use to eliminate direct object references.
> 2. Check access. Each use of a direct object reference from an untrusted source must include an access control check to ensure the user is authorized for the requested object.

I have used the Access Reference Map from their ESAPI -- it was pretty straightforward.  Our unique IDs were simply replaced with random strings, which were tied to a user's session.

Comment: I don't quite understand this approach and what changes it will involve on my end. I plan to research this more

Comment: @Omnipresent The basic approach is just creating a HashMap that maps from the SSN to a randomly generated string/number.  Before building your view, you generate this string/number, store it in the HashMap (which you should put on the user's session) and then your JSP uses the generated ID.  When the page is submitted you will need to lookup the SSN from the HashMap. Once the user's session expires the generated id has no meaning. This isn't difficult to roll your own, but the OWASP ESAPI has made it a little bit easier.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you should not pass the SSN around more than necessary. But assuming we have an internal account id, I'm not sure what the above really gains you over just requring a password to log in and establish a session to begin with. An internal id is no use outside your system, and if they can't access it without a password, what does hiding it gain? Maybe I should read the referenced page  -- no point drawing conclusions from a two-paragraph summary.

Answer (score 1):

You should be encrypting your SSN on the database side due to its sensitivity. SSN should not be stored as plain text values because they are fully visible for hacker access. Look at SONY, and the many more companies getting hacked.

I would say encrypt them in your database using database encrypt functions. I don't know what database you are targeting MySQL or Oracle or etc). You then can just use the encrypted SSN from the database. Here is a mysql reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html